# Could you clarify difference among Bettola, Osteria, Taverna, Trattoria, Ristorante and Locanda, Pensione, Albergo, Hotel?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

I am researching local or tourist-oriented facilities in regards of Food/Lodging industry.

Could you please clarify the difference among,

- Bettola
- Osteria
- Taverna
- Trattoria
- Ristorante

And among

- Locanda
- Pensione
- Albergo
- Hotel

I did look all these words in Ragazzini's dictionary, but it is still not clear if there are socio-economical or cultural distinctions, a grading, or a scale of perception of values, not really economical, but of quality?

For example, I heard some would try first Trattorias first, before restaurants, as their "cucina" is supposed to be more genuine?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: This is a [related question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/6114) which partially answers yours.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, and for the link. I did see that question, but I would need a clarification in relation to the full scope of those words. It would seem that, in context, they refer to specific realities of the Italian cultural and socio-economic landscape? Thanks again.

Comment: ***Trattoria, Taverna, Osteria, Bettola: sinonimi?*** http://italianoquestosconosciuto.blogspot.com/2010/03/trattoria-taverna-osteria-bettola.html

Comment: That is an excellent resource (too bad some linked photos are missing!). Would you wish to give a partial answer to my question, so I can vote for it? In Italian would be preferable, so I can study it.

Comment: Keep in mind that the source quoted in that blog post is  [a notoriously unreliably old etymology dictionary](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1202/37).

Comment: If anything, I suggest browsing the not exactly new either, but good dictionary of synonyms by Niccolò Tommaseo: for instance, [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=DUmx1dC3CRIC&lpg=PA984&ots=7T_LXi3xmw&pg=PA984#v=onepage&q&f=false) (see “taverna”) and [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=DUmx1dC3CRIC&lpg=PA984&ots=7T_LXi3xmw&pg=PA984#v=onepage&q&f=false) (see “osteria”).

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, ora ti spiegherò la differenza:

Bettola: ristorante di paese, di basso livello, che serve piatti tipici e semplici (spesso con connotazione negativa)

Osteria: molto simile alla bettola, ma leggermente più raffinata

Taverna: dove vivo io si ha la tradizione di fare i pranzi nelle occasioni speciali oppure la domenica, è un posto spesso interrato e per il resto simile all'osteria

Trattoria: via di mezzo tra bettola e osteria

Ristorante: la forma più raffinata per esprimere il concetto di un luogo dove si va a mangiare.

---

Locanda: frequentemente una trattoria, ma anche delle camere, e' tutto piuttosto grezzo

Pensione: Alloggio semplice che provvede al tuo cibo a colazione, pranzo e cena, ma non è aperto a chi non soggiorna in esso

Albergo: Hotel, può essere molto ricercato come semplice e grezzo

Hotel: Uguale ad albergo, solo in inglese

Spero di esserti stato utile :D

Comment: Thank you, this is clarifying, useful and instructive. I upvoted. Not sure why somebody downvoted, such answer to me is exemplary in completeness and clarity.